Equal (=) Symbol Not Working in Visual Studio Code
I'm encountering an unusual issue in Visual Studio Code (VS Code) where the equal to (=) symbol doesn't seem to function properly. Whenever I attempt to type the equal symbol, it doesn't register or appear on the screen. This problem is hindering my coding workflow, especially when I'm working with assignments or comparisons.
I've tried several troubleshooting steps, including:

Restarting VS Code.
Restarting my computer.
Checking for any conflicting keyboard shortcuts within VS Code.
Verifying that my keyboard hardware is functioning correctly by testing it in other applications.

Despite these efforts, the problem persists. It's worth noting that this issue only seems to occur within VS Code; the equal symbol works fine in other applications and text editors.
Has anyone else experienced a similar problem in VS Code? If so, how did you resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Is this a VS code problem?

Did you accidentally do a keybinding on it?  File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts

Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. What do you see when you troubleshoot your keybindings? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post. Include also the top section of the file opened by running Developer: Inspect Key Mappings in the command palette and all following text that is related to the keys of interest.

If you copy/paste one from another editor does it show up? I assume so since you specifically mentioned typing, but you never know, you might be using the no equals font. :)
